# save symfony/workflow in database using mysqli php

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, workflow

im new in symfony/workflow so i read the documentation and do my first workflow in my exist hp project, i added the code like this :

```
$definitionBuilder = new DefinitionBuilder();

$definition = $definitionBuilder->addPlaces(['create_contest', 'approve', 'reject', 'launch_contest','contest_edit','submition','not_submition','pay_contest','pass','full','post_mortem','final_review','fail','final_pass','completed'])

    // Transitions are defined with a unique name, an origin place and a destination place
    ->addTransition(new Transition('pending_contest', 'create_contest','approve','reject'))
    ->addTransition(new Transition('Pending_contest', 'contest_edit', 'approve','reject'))
    ->addTransition(new Transition('admin_approve', 'approve', 'launch_contest'))
    ->addTransition(new Transition('admin_reject', 'reject', 'contest_edit'))
    ->addTransition(new Transition('wait_to_pay', 'launch_contest','pay_contest'))
    ->addTransition(new Transition('submition_phase', 'pay_contest', 'submition','not_submition'))
    ->addTransition(new Transition('review','submition','pass','full'))
    ->addTransition(new Transition('post_mortem', 'not_submition','post_mortem'))
    ->addTransition(new Transition('Post_mortem', 'full', 'post_mortem'))
    ->addTransition(new Transition('final_fixes','pass','final_review'))
    ->addTransition(new Transition('Final_fixes','fail','final_review'))
    ->addTransition(new Transition('fail','final_review','fail'))
    ->addTransition(new Transition('pass','final_review','final_pass'))
    ->addTransition(new Transition('approve','final_pass','completed'))
    ->build();

$marking = new SingleStateMarkingStore('currentState');
$workflow = new Workflow($definition, $marking);
```

so .. what i need to do after this ? do i need to add more code like controller stuff ? how to use the transitions ? the code i add it after create new contest,  so i need to call the first transition and save it in database using Mysqli
i need help please

Comment: Please read the [ask] and do not share your code as image.

Answer (score -1):

Here read this [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/3.4/workflow/usage.html)

and try this [example](http://symfony-workflow-demo.herokuapp.com/):

may be you rushed to ask and missed to read those docs "_"